# ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*'

Tags: c++, строки, классы, указатели, iso

Создал класс Human. Прототипы методов get() и set() объявил в Human.h. Human.cpp с реализацией функций тоже есть. Вот часть класса:

```
void Human::setFirst_name(char* first_name){

    First_name = first_name;
}
char* Human::getFirst_name(){
    return First_name;
}
```

В файле main.cpp заполнил поле, вот так:

```
first_h.setFirst_name("Василий");
```

Выдает предупреждение. Как избавиться?

Human.cpp

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <clocale>
 #include <cstring>
 #include <ctime>
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include "Human.h"



namespace Myspace{

Human::Human(void) {

}

~Human::Human(void) {

}

void Human::setFirst_name(const char* first_name){  
First_name = first_name;
}
const char* Human::getFirst_name() const {
return First_name;
}
```

Human.h

```
   #pragma once
   namespace Myspace{
typedef unsigned int ui;
class Human{
private:
    const char * First_name;
    char * Patronymic;
    char * Last_name;
    ui Date_of_birth;
    ui Age;
    bool Sex;

public:
    void setFirst_name(char*);
    char* getFirst_name();

    void setPatronymic(char*);
    char* getPatronymic();

    void setLast_name(char*);
    char* getLast_name();

    ui getDate_of_birth();
    void setDate_of_birth(ui);

    ui getAge();
    void setAge(ui);

    bool getSex();
    void setSex(ui);
};
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Human.h"

using namespace std;

using Myspace::Human;

 int main (void){

  SetConsoleCP(1251);
  SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

  Human first_h;

   first_h.setFirst_name("Василий");
}
```

Comment: Как объявлно поле/переменная `First_name`?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов char * First_name;

Comment: Почитайте, пожалуйста, как создать [mcve].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Надо не просто *избавляться* от предупреждений, а понимать, откуда они и что означают, и как изменить свое решение.

Строковый литерал - это по стандарту константный массив, который не может быть изменен. У вас же он передается как изменяемый, так что вы в вашей функции можете его изменять - а это недопустимо.

Вы можете использовать, например, `const char *` или скопировать передаваемую строку в свой объект - но как именно поступить, зависит от дизайна вашего класса - планируете ли вы владение строкой, или она всегда должна быть где-то "снаружи" (и тогда ее время жизни должно быть больше времени жизни соответствующего объекта).

Comment: Если использовать const char * выдает ту же ошибку + C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd4N3oh.o:LW4.cpp:(.text+0x41):

Comment: **Как** вы его использовали? И тогда уж приведите объявление класса...

Comment: Добавил в Human.cpp.вот так: 
 void Human::setFirst_name(const char* first_name){  
 First_name = first_name;
}

Comment: А `First_name` оставили `char*`? Т.е. решили разрешить менять константную строку не прямо в функции, а потом, через указатель `First_name`? :) Нет уж, полумеры в таком деле не помогут. Еще раз повторю - **Надо не просто избавляться от предупреждений, а понимать, откуда они и что означают, и как изменить свое решение.**

Comment: Сделал First_name const char* не помогло. Отредактировал вопрос. Привожу полный код всех файлов.

Comment: Оно у вас вообще компилироваться не должно - в классе объявляете одни функции (от `char*` и не `const`), а в реализации - другие! Исправье в объявлении класса объявления         `void setFirst_name(const char*);
        const char* getFirst_name() const;`

Comment: Я тут собрал ваш код в один файл, чтоб ideoneсъел - вот, смотрите, все работает: https://ideone.com/iFRL2X  Только вот обидно, что вы все пытаетесь заткнуть дыры чопиками, вместо чтоб поменять трубы... **Надо не просто избавляться от предупреждений, а понимать, откуда они и что означают, и как изменить свое решение.**

Comment: Спасибо, что показали. Я недавно начал изучать С++, поэтому простите за испорченные нервы, если что...

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что указатель на строку "Василий" является константой.  Необходимо добавить ключевое слово `const`.

```
void Human::setFirst_name(const char* first_name){

    First_name = first_name;
}

const char* Human::getFirst_name(){
    return First_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Как избавиться?

Старательным соблюдением правил константной корректности. Если вы не собираетесь модифицировать данные через указатель, то этот указатель должен быть указателем на константу. В данном случае

```
void Human::setFirst_name(const char* first_name){  
    First_name = first_name;
}
const char* Human::getFirst_name() const {
    return First_name;
}
```

Однако это означает, что и `First_name` тоже должно стать `const char*`. А устраивает ли это вас - из того что вы привели не видно. И это отдельная тема для размышлений: что вы хотите хранить в своем классе. Указатель на внешнюю строку? Указатель на "свою" строку?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще это принцип такой: если Вы в функции не собираетесь менять аргумент, то лучше передайте его как `сonst`. И вообще, расставляйте константы везде, если не знаете, надо или нет. Если не откомпилится, то уберите. Метод от противного. Это по простому. А так, ведь по коду функции видно, надо вам константа или нет. Лишние константы не помешают. Просто когда переменная или аргумент константный, то компилятор может выполнить более глубокую оптимизацию.